# How to compile and run IOS app without using from command line tool without using code?

Tags: ios

How to compile and run IOS app from command line tool without using code?
Note: Without using xcode

Answer (score 0):

Check [xcodebuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html).

There are a lot of options though.

EDIT : You will indeed need to have Xcode installed anyway.

Comment: Hi thnx for ur reply,but when i run the xcode build its giving error msg like this is not a xcode project. actually i am generating app from java code, so its not a xcode project.

Comment: AH. I'm not an expert with Java stuff. Anyway, it seems that you'll have to use 'javac' to "compile" .java files and generate .class files